# Numpy: sort Matrix's elements by index

Tags: css, arrays, numpy, matrix, indexing

I need to sort a matrix, defined by an array like

```
example = np.array([[00, 01, 02, 03, 04],
               [10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
               [20, 21, 22, 23, 24],
               [30, 31, 32, 33, 34],
               [40, 41, 42, 43, 44]])
```

through a list of index, as `index = [1, 3]`, and obtain:

```
example = np.array([[11, 13, 10, 12, 14],
               [31, 33, 30, 32, 34],
               [01, 03, 00, 02, 04],
               [21, 23, 30, 22, 24],
               [41, 43, 40, 42, 44]])
```

where the first high-left 2x2 submatrix is composed by the elements in position [1,1], [1,3], [3,1] and [3,3].

I used a for-cycle and [numpy.extract](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.extract.html) (I think this isn't correct), but I'm sure that the easiest way exists.

Comment: Have you tried writing code to solve your problem? If so, please post it. StackOverflow is not a code-writing service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create the permutation you want in `permutation` and then use:

```
e = example[:, permutation][permutation,:]
```

For instance in your case:

```
permutation = [1, 3, 0, 2, 4]
```